# Pivoting and unpivoting data in power Bi

Tags: powerbi, pivot

I have data that looked like this:

[image]

It has a unique recordid column, and then three repeating columns:  email, is_this_study_feasible, and please_advise.   (is_this_study_feasible_v2...etc..)

I'd love to transform this from wide to long and be left with something like this where I can tell what each person said about each record id:

[image]

I'm most of the way there but running into some problems. I've followed many of the steps from this article:  https://kohera.be/power-bi/how-to-unpivot-twice/ and my data currently looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, when I select the attribute column and "pivot" it using values from the value column (with no aggregation), I get thrown errors:

[image]

Looks like the errors are from trying to pivot identical values.  I.e. row 17 and 21 are effectively the same.

So I read somewhere I could add an index column and then pivot, KINDA works, but everything gets put in the wrong spot:

[image]

I need to be able to tell what Jcrozier (me, from the "email1" column) said about whether the study was feasible (the first "is_this_feasible" column).

Any tips would be appreciated

**Update**

David's code below seemed to work, but I ran into a problem.  When I added data (not new columns/rows, just a filled in field) that wasn't in original question like so:

[image]

It didn't make it "past" that code:
[image]

I've included the .pbix file here for reference:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnsEucAtFS_SlsxHIs-VCHr-BHUxew?e=e3PlVq

Comment: You should be able to modify my answer at [How do I Transpose an Excel Table to Unique columns from many duplicate rows](https://superuser.com/questions/1728712/how-do-i-transpose-an-excel-table-to-unique-columns-from-many-duplicate-rows-p) in superusers.  It shows two methods of dealing with this error.

Comment: I think you want to un-pivot and THEN pivot, the data set.

https://databear.com/power-bi-pivot-and-unpivot-columns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to advanced editor and paste in the text below and it will work for you. I have removed the token value in line 3 so don't forget to update that from your original query.

```
 let
        actualUrl = "https://redcap.lifespan.org/redcap/api/",
        record  =[token="TOKEN_REMOVED",
        content="record",
        format="csv"
        ],
        body = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(record)),
        options = [Headers =[#"Content-type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"], Content=body],
        result = Web.Contents(actualUrl, options),
        #"Imported CSV" = Csv.Document(result,[Delimiter=",", Columns=33, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv]),
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Imported CSV", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"protocol_title", "short_title", "principal_investigator", "filepath_for_protocol", "is_imaging_manual_included", "filepath_for_imaging_manua", "number_of_patients_expecte", "approximate_length_of_the", "approximate_number_of_part", "name_of_research_coordinat", "email_address_of_research", "any_other_special_instruct", "protocol_information_complete", "emailsurvey", "email_list_complete", "collaboration_survey_complete", "collaboration_survey_2_complete", "collaboration_survey_3_complete", "collaboration_survey_4_complete", "method_of_image"}),
        Custom1 = let
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "ListOfRecords", each {[email = [email1], is_this_study_feasible =[is_this_study_feasible], please_advise = [please_advise] ],[email = [email2], is_this_study_feasible =[is_this_study_feasible_v2] , please_advise = [please_advise_v2]],[email = [email3], is_this_study_feasible =[is_this_study_feasible_v3], please_advise = [please_advise_v3] ],[email = [email4], is_this_study_feasible =[is_this_study_feasible_v4], please_advise = [please_advise_v4] ]}),
        #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"recordid", "ListOfRecords"}),
        #"Expanded ListOfRecords" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "ListOfRecords"),
        #"Expanded ListOfRecords1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded ListOfRecords", "ListOfRecords", {"email", "is_this_study_feasible", "please_advise"}, {"email", "is_this_study_feasible", "please_advise"})
    in
        #"Expanded ListOfRecords1",
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Custom1,{{"email", "Respondent"}, {"is_this_study_feasible", "Is This Study Feasible?"}, {"please_advise", "Please Advise"}}),
        #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns", {"recordid"}, #"Protocol Info", {"recordid"}, "Protocol Info", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
        #"Expanded Protocol Info" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Protocol Info", {"Protocol Title"}, {"Protocol Info.Protocol Title"})
    in
        #"Expanded Protocol Info"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("XU3NCoMwDH6V0rOIDrz3umcQD7FkJpoaaetlT7+O7qCDwPeXj28cbW8bu/qob8bohF+YDthbjUvx43aSBNgd/wWa8KBfaegHR5oDsLReQ0nL9RW6Cl5VKhMI+GVTM9pHIbPO7tJcFa9yQ84EtwcWcfep7rb4NAQZDWeT1ITTU7XTGbExorolAxJ5oWyn6QM=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [recordid = _t, email1 = _t, email2 = _t, email3 = _t, email4 = _t, is_this_study_feasible1 = _t, is_this_study_feasible2 = _t, is_this_study_feasible3 = _t, is_this_study_feasible4 = _t, please_advise1 = _t, please_advise2 = _t, please_advise3 = _t, please_advise4 = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ListOfRecords", each {[email = [email1], is_this_study_feasible =[is_this_study_feasible1], please_advise = [please_advise1] ],[email = [email2], is_this_study_feasible =[is_this_study_feasible2] , please_advise = [please_advise2]],[email = [email3], is_this_study_feasible =[is_this_study_feasible3], please_advise = [please_advise3] ],[email = [email4], is_this_study_feasible =[is_this_study_feasible4], please_advise = [please_advise4] ]}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"recordid", "ListOfRecords"}),
    #"Expanded ListOfRecords" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "ListOfRecords"),
    #"Expanded ListOfRecords1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded ListOfRecords", "ListOfRecords", {"email", "is_this_study_feasible", "please_advise"}, {"email", "is_this_study_feasible", "please_advise"})
in
    #"Expanded ListOfRecords1"
```

Comment: Thank you for this, away from the work computer today.  Will try tomorrow and accept answer if it works.

Comment: This worked, and I accepted it.... but actually it may not work.  Let me explain:  All the data that was in the example above got transposed just as it should and looked exactly like the solution data you provided.  However if I added any data (for example in bob or Keitha's row where its blank, if I filled something in... it doesnt make it 'past' your code into the final data.  If that makes sense.  Do you know why?

Comment: It should work even if you add data in the existing fields. There must be something else going wrong. Can you post your file that is going wrong?

Comment: I'd love to share it but the source is an API I probably shouldnt just throw up on the internet.  There's no private info in it though so I'd feel safe enough emailing/messaging it to you.  Can I do that?

Comment: Can you not create a minimum reproducible example of what is going wrong. Do you understand the code I have sent - i.e. it is creating a record from 4 specifically named fields. If this doesn't work. there are other approaches like using an index as you originally tried.

Comment: Here I'll just play it risky and add the whole file, I'll also include some more info about how its not working.  One second

Comment: I have updated my answer. You hadn't renamed the fields according to your source and you were actually still using my test data.